# ASP.NET MVC - Alternatives to databases

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, appharbor

I thought about splitting this up, but i think it's better as one big question. Here it goes. :-)

Warning: this question is in-depth. :-)

I've been working with ASP.NET for a little while now. Just a few days ago, after watching a course on MVC at [Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/), i decided to try it out. Development was amazing and very easy, especially with the Entity Framework 4.1. As i searched around for deployment options, i found [AppHarbor](http://appharbor.com).  Unfortunately, i ran into some problems. See, i can't just magically port my databases over with the git commit AppHarbor requires.  The problem is, I've never really worked with databases - they've always just worked [automagically](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26618/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-the-word-automagically-when-we-already-have-autom). I'm scared stiff of connection strings and the like. I managed to get a database set up on AppHarbor for the ASP.NET Membership stuff (I still need to figure out how to copy over the data and schemas, but i'll figure that out :-)) but i'm clueless on what to do about the Entity Framework SQL Server Compact database, which i'm using to store blog posts and comments. Problems:

1. It's not working - MVC/EntityFramwork/Whatever-Is-Automagically-Working-Behind-The-Scenes isn't firing up a new database or whatever
2. AppHarbor only allows 1 database (for the free version)

Potential Solutions?

1. Combine the databases. I have no idea how to do this or how i would keep the EntityFramework's Auto-Magic working.
2. Adopt a non-database solution for the posts/comments. I realize databases are incredibly more efficient as there's a sort of interface between the literal file and the programs accesing it, so you don't have file locking and stuff. So what would be the best alternative?

### My Question

What's the best way to handle this situation? Not just this particular situation, but the general situation of "crap-i-hate-databases"?

Ways to answer:

1. Recommending that i learn about databases: fine, but please provide some good resources.
2. Giving a non-database alternative: awesome.
3. Explaining what i need to do to get this all working on AppHarbor (but more generally any deploy server): ideal. I may even set up a bounty just to award it

Thanks so much in advance; I realize this is a deepish question and the rep garnered may not be worth it. Please let me know if i need to provide any more information.

Comment: to the close-voter: if you could comment explaining what's wrong with my question, that'd be great. I like to know where i'm going wrong. :-)

Comment: Reads like a blog post, instead of an actual question.

Comment: @George i was just trying to provide some decent context for my problem. I thought i isolated the actual question pretty well, and i don't see how this doesn't adhere to the FAQ... but if you have any suggestions for improvement, that'd be great. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider checking out a document database like [Raven DB](http://ravendb.net/).

Comment: thanks, this looks interesting. Checking it out.

Comment: @Thomas Shields: Yeah, I'm also in the "crap-i-hate-databases" category and Raven is what I'd rather deal with. Oren Eini recently created a [blog engine named RacoonBlog](https://github.com/ayende/RaccoonBlog) if you want to check out how he uses it.

Comment: The warning with Document Databases is that with a git push you can erase the data uploaded to appharbor if you haven't done a pull first

Comment: @Hurricanepkt righto. thanks for the reminder. @ataddeini cool, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I am going against the grain and suggest you do not use EF and generate a whole bunch of scaffolding code using MVC3. Simplify your app and really learn what is going on. That way you will be able to debug and add features.

Try taking your existing database and building an MVC3 app with [Massive](http://blog.wekeroad.com/helpy-stuff/and-i-shall-call-it-massive). Really simple and confrontable.You will get over your database phobia when you see how easy it is.

Comment: +1 for thinking outside the box here. While i probably won't end up doing this (mostly just because i'm lazy) I may come back to it and i appreciate you're trying to remove my database paranoia. :-)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to Create some objects using Entity Framework 4.1 (called code first)

the Gu (Scott Guthrie) has some simple walkthroughs that will give you a start ... and instead of SQLCE4 you can point to the Appharbor SQL server address

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/03/19/rc-of-entity-framework-4-1-which-includes-ef-code-first.aspx
 (best resource and links to the others)
 shouldnt be more than half an hour before you have real data running to a database...

Comment: Benefit with Code first you worry about your objects and the DB just works behind the scenes once you do the fairly simple step of saying what db you want to connect to

Comment: Thanks, but this is already what I'm doing. This doesn't quite answer my question (if you'll notice, i laid out three ways one could answer) ...I do like the idea of just connecting right to the AppHarbor database, and i'll check out that link and get back to you.